# Static IP in VirtualBox Machine with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a Virtual machine as a guest OS on my mac.

as always I have set it up with NAT and "Host Only" with the following configuration the way I had all my other VM Boxes with Ubuntu 14.04 to have static IP and Internet. but they seem not to work with the new Ubuntu. although "ifconfig" is giving me an OK result, I don't have Internet and I cannot reach my guest machine from my host machine with the mentioned IP.

my /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.56.106
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and the result of "ifconfig -a" looks something like this:

[image]

any Idea why this is not working on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Please note: I have restarted my network service(/etc/init.d/networking) and machine completely some hundred times.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about Linux; not programming.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess the problem was the new naming in Ubuntu 16.04. so I set my first Adapter to "Host-only Adapter" and second one to "NAT" and i could successfully get my IP set to "192.168.56.106" with following configuration.
here is my     `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Host Only Network
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
address 192.168.56.106
network 192.168.56.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255

# NAT Network
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Thanks. I've set as `Attached to: Bridged Adapter`. It works.

Comment: Thank you. You just saved my sanity.

Comment: Thanks. I set enp0s3 as NAT network instead and it works as well. For the Host-only, I only keep 4 lines:  (1) auto enp0s3  
(2) iface enp0s3 inet static  
(3) address 192.168.56.106  
(4) netmask 255.255.255.0

Comment: Where do I find the file "/etc/network/interfaces"? On Host or Guest? My Host is mac and Guest is Vicidial ( Linux OpenSuse)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding the following at the end of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Please note that I configured the first network adapter as "host-only" and the second one as NAT.

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm this: the order of the network adapters in the VirtualBox settings makes the difference. First one should be host-only, second one NAT.